# USB antivirus scanner

Tags: windows, usb, antivirus

I'm using Avast for protecting my PC but it could not detect and repair the damage caused by viruses to my removable drives. In the meanwhile it also fails to detect several USB threats.

So I need an USB antivirus which will work fine with any primary antivirus and should scan and remove all threats effectively.

Comment: There is never a guarantee, that the damage done by a virus is reversable at all. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more about what the damage is (is it encrypted content) or which virus caused it? With your question you will get a lot of "I use this scanner" answers, which may or may not help you.

Comment: I wouldn't run executables on USB. USB Disk security has a free version.

Comment: Why do you think "normal" antiviruses can't detect viruses on USBs? They're just a normal drive that happens to be removable.

Comment: I think that the intention is to have a USB bootable version.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is SUPERAntiSpyware. It works fine with other anti-virus software including Avast. It's free to use (for personal use) and is being updated every day. It includes a portable version that is available to install on USB drives. This software picks up nearly everything from cookies on a browser to malware installed and allows you to choose what to remove and what to search for.

## [SUPERAntiSpyware Portable Scanner](http://www.superantispyware.com/portablescanner.html) (free*)

> SUPERAntiSpyware is a software application which can detect and remove spyware, adware, malware, trojans, rogue software, worms, rootkits, parasites and other potentially harmful software applications, as well as restore modified system settings.
>
> The scanner features our complete scanning and removal engine and will detect AND remove over 1,000,000 spyware/malware infections. The scanner contains the latest definitions so you DO NOT need Internet Access on the infected system to scan.
>
> [image: Screenshot]

*for personal use

Comment: Mmm, I _love_ those classical anti-spyware snakeoil-like programs. Feel the wrath of the Spyware Spanker™ ... no one expects the Spyware Inquisition™ ... to me the names of these products form a whole (funny) genre  ... SAS isn't exactly very sophisticated, I analyzed it once (RCE) because my employer was thinking about licensing it. We backed down after seeing the details. Having worked for one of the early antispyware vendors, I can't say I was too surprised, though. You could say a lot of these products are basically faith-based. But if that works for you ...

Comment: It is no longer **FREE** for personal use, was it ever ?

Answer (score 1):

Norton AV has a bootable USB stick for system scanning.

Also you can not trust a USB stick/portable app antivirus to scan a running system because an active rootkit will just hide all of its activities from the AV, and the AV product will never find anything!

You have to remember that the virus people always have a jump on the AV people.  Most of the good virus writers, scan their viruses with a dozen or more AV products to make sure they don't detect them.

In this 0-day period there is no protection against them, or de-infections tools.  Even when a virus is detected it may damage the files in a non-recoverable way.  Only files altered in a known formulaic method are fixable.

You are better off with a firewall to monitor and detect traffic to unusual locations.  Even then virus authors are encrypting the viruses, and changing the key so that they don't match the pre-programmed signatures that most AV depend upon.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend [Emsisoft Emergency Kit](https://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/eek/).

I use Emsisoft's antivirus and so far I didn't notice any false negatives so I assume that you can trust Emsisoft. You can also take a look at antivirus benchmarks online to see for yourself.

Comment: Does this work well with other antivirus packages? That is a requirement by the OP and quite an important one, because having two AV packages present is generally not recommended.

Comment: @JanDoggen It's not mentioned anywhere on their website, but it is working with Emsisoft AV and AVG without a problem. I don't know about other AVs

Comment: I also recommend Emsisoft. Emsisoft uses 2 powerful scan engines (Emsisoft's own one + BitDefender antivirus engine.This is a good review of [Emsisoft Antivirus](http://www.raritysoft.com/reviews/emsisoft-anti-malware-review)

Answer (score 0):

I use the free version of [Panda antivirus](http://www.pandasecurity.com/usa/homeusers/solutions/free-antivirus/) and it has a little feature called USB Protection that will automatically scan and "vaccine" USB sticks when you plug them in.

Apart from that this antivirus is efficient and quiet, and won't bother you with ads or pop-up reminders that there is a paid version.

It does the job for me and it really is a pleasure to use when you come, like me, from Avira or, even worse, Avast in your case. ;)

Comment: This cant work if something on the USB does auto-play